# Is there a way to stop protractor after it throws a timeout exception?

Tags: angularjs, testing, timeout, protractor, angularjs-e2e

Quite often there is the chance that protractor test specs throws a timeout exception.

To make debugging and troubleshooting easier, I would like to stop protractor just after a timeout exception and prevent it to continue running test.

But trying to catch timeout exception at each promise looks quite ugly to do.

Is there any other way to stop protractor when it throws a timeout exception?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option will be [`protractor-fail-fast`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-fail-fast) Only in case `jasmine-fail-fast` doesn't work for you.

> This Protractor plugin is essentially a wrapper around `jasmine-fail-fast`, solving the problem of halting multiple Protractor instances once one of them has failed. Otherwise, a multi-capability Protractor test will take as long as the longest running test instance, potentially as long as if `jasmine-fail-fast` wasn't applied at all.

Comment: it worked! just a micro improvements in the deep hell of end to end test with protractor and ie

Answer (score 1):

One option would be to let jasmine *exit on the first failure* via [`jasmine-fail-fast`](https://github.com/Updater/jasmine-fail-fast):

> Allow Jasmine tests to "fail-fast", exiting on the first failure
>   instead of running all tests no matter what. This can save a great
>   deal of time running slow, expensive tests, such as Protractor e2e
>   tests.